# Javascript CSS display not working when called from an onClick event dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an HTML table dynamically and adding an onClick event in each title cell dynamically as well. (The goal of my project is re order the columns of the html table using the onClick event).
The event is being called perfectly, however if I try to set the display of a div inside that function the display event never fires or only fires once the function ends. In my case I am trying to show a loading image while my function executes.
Please see here my code, any help is most than welcome.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container body">
  <div class="report_main_container">
    <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-lg text-center new-rprt-chgs loading-container">
      <div class="loading-over" id="loading-over">
        <img src="loading.gif">
      </div>

      <table class="table table-striped" id="main_report_table" style="display: none">
        <thead id="fixedHeader"></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
var row_head = '';
var row_head_reporte = [];
row_head += '<tr>';

for (let i = 0; i < my_report["columns"].length; i++) {
  // console.log(my_report["columns"][i]);
  if (my_report["columns"][i]["VISIBLE"] == "YES") {
    row_head += '<th onclick="sortTable(' + i + ')">' + my_report["columns"][i]["NAME"] + '</th>';


  }
}

row_head += '</tr>';

$("#main_report_table thead").append(row_head);

function sortTable(n) {

  $(".loading-over").show(); // This never fires!!!!

  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("main_report_table");
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
  $(".loading-over").hide();
}
```

Comment: Pages have to be given a chance to redraw after changes are made.  If your logic is adding a class, doing a bunch of logic, and then hiding the class, there is a chance that the browser is never being given a chance to redraw.

Comment: It does not look like your logic is doing anything non-procedurally, so my assumption would be the redraw is not allowed to happen before the function finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Taplar, but what is your solution? How can I get a simple load image while doing my function if my function was add in an click event dynamically? Thanks

Comment: So the first question I would have is how long is it taking for your function to finish?  If it is finishing quickly, do you actually need the loader?  Otherwise, you could always throw your logic after the `.show()` into a function that you call after a `setTimeout`

Comment: @Taplar setTimout works like a charm! Thanks!!!